# Users under the age of 13 years

Tags: facebook, web, instagram, verification, snapchat

Instagram, Snapchat etc. Terms of Service state that they do not allow any users under the age of 13 years, yet their platforms are flooded with young children.

My Question: In a web or mobile app for users **under the age of 13 years**, how can I design a verification flow that allows me to obtain **"verifiable parental consent"** in accordance with the US COPPA and EU GDPR laws?

I am aware that I can request the parent to provide their **credit card information**, which I believe will count as "verifiable parental consent". However, I am wondering if there are other options with a lower potential bounce-rate?

*If this seems "too broad" a question, I am specifically looking for a verification flow that allows the parent to choose from different verification options. A flow chart would be great!*

Comment: This *is* quite broad, and also doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: It's a question a programmer faces when implementing an application in a real world scenario where some users are adults and others... are not.

Comment: Not everything related to development is on topic here. If you were having problems with your code itself, that would definitely be ontopic. A list of ways to verify age though isn't related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

#### The short answer

there really isn't a good way to reliably verify someone's age without potentially alienating some segment of your user-base.

#### The long answer

Even your credit card solution doesn't really work for children between the ages of 13 and 18 years, where one wouldn't reasonably expect them to have credit cards or get their parents to verify age using theirs.

Some people would outright refrain from sharing other identifying documents like driver's licenses or passports out of concerns like identity-theft.

**If your concerns are merely legal**, then you can follow Facebook's Verification Model viz. an honor-based system coupled with a secondary mobile phone or email verification.

On the other hand, **if your concerns are more towards improving user-experience**, then any combination of some of the aforementioned sources of verification - Government-issued ID, Credit Cards, Phone Number, Email ID, etc. can be used depending how inclusive or exclusive you want to make your software service. You could also look to outsource this problem by relying on external authentication source(s) like Facebook Login and use the user-data collected to verify age-range.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but I was under the impression ages 13-18 do not require parental consent? Also, could you elaborate on Facebook's Verification Model? My concerns are legal, I want to support users < 13 but don't want any legal issues.

Comment: Ages 13-18 don't require parental consent but nothing stops an under 13 user from setting their birth year for age 14 to bypass any consent requirements. Facebook's verification revolves around confirming a security code received on the user's or a parent's email address and/or on their mobile phone.

Specifics at https://www.facebook.com/help/157793540954833